# Installing Foreman - ERROR 107 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, passenger, puppet, theforeman

I'm trying to install Foreman in a VM Ubuntu Server 12.04, so I followed this manual page : http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.1/index.html#3.InstallingForeman

I'd rather install with the Installer, but actually, I got a 107 error when I go to

```
https://fqdn/
```

(Of course, I don't write fqdn literraly).
Puppet modules go well, no problem. And when I type

```
https://fqdn/:8443
```

Everything's fine, I got a response from the serv.
I think the passenger module for apache is disturbing in a certain way, but I never used it before.

Then I tried the others ways to install it, package way gives me the same result.

But, the install from sources ways (latest stable) is working BUT the server runs on Webrick, and I want Passenger.

Has someone an issue with this ? And/or a solution ? Thank you :)

Comment: what package manager are you using ? What do you mean by "package way gives me the same result" ? I don't understand the problem you are having, could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: I follow the exact Installation with the Installer (3.2), but when I try to connect to Foreman, I get a 107 Error.
So it does with the 3.3, I'm using Aptitude on Ubuntu.
Because of the 107 Error, I'm not able to use Foreman.